# wordpress -> custom taxonomy -> hierarchical (false, means tags like) -> template

Tags: wordpress, custom-taxonomy

I want to show custom taxonomies. But when I try to show only taxonomies wordpress takes me to 404 page.

I have taxonomy TV Series, and I can show All the terms in the TV Series Taxonomy by utilizing template {taxonomy-tv_series.php} "tv_series" is the taxonomy name. Bellow is the working url.

http://mysite.com/tv-series/lost/

and I can show all the posts inside the lost on {taxonomy-tv_series.php}. But I want to show / list all the tv-series itself like

tv-series-template.php and it displays.

a) Lost b) Prison Break c) Breaking Bad etc.

by using url like this

http://mysite.com/tv-series/

If my question is not clear to you guys, please let me know I will try to make it more usefull.

I am using pretty permalink "%spost_name%s"

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Currently WordPress doesn't offer an archive that displays everything tagged inside a taxonomy.

You could create a [custom page template](http://codex.wordpress.org/Pages#Page_Templates) called "TV Series" and [manually query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) all posts associated with your taxonomy.

Alternatively you could create a [custom post type](http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types#Custom_Types) e.g. called "Tv Show" and connect it to your taxonomy. Then you would use archive-{post-type}.php to display all posts inside your taxonomy.

You can read more about template hierarchy at the codex page:
http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy

Comment: Thanks Jan for answer, but I was hoping for archive thing from the default wordpress (instead of create page templates or hooking into the custom post type & connect). Actually I wanted to be safe as much as possible. But I guess I will have to go with custom page template way & query all terms on that page. Thanks again.